# AppEngine - JDO query on list field

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I am working with AppEngine for Java, and I have a JDO entity defined as follows:

```
Quote
| id(Long) | quote(String) | author(String) |
```

I realized my quote could be from multiple authors in case I wanna capture a short discussion, so I need to change author from a simple `String` to a `List<String>`.

I seem to understand I can now query by single (or multiple) author by using the IN operator instead of the standard ==, like this:

```
Query q = _pm.newQuery(Quote.class);
//q.setFilter("author == authorParam");
q.setFilter("author IN [authorParam]");
q.declareParameters("String authorParam");
```

Will this work with the Java SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since when has "IN" been a JDOQL keyword? JDOQL shares syntax with Java, so use of *{collectionObj}.contains(Object)* is what all docs on the subject say, where collectionObj could be an input collection parameter

Comment: Thanks for your reply - "since when" <-- I am asking because I do not know :) I take it it's q.setFilter("author.contains(authorParam)")? A link to the relevant section of the docs would help a lot